# Strategy for expanding the function $e^{e^x-1}$ into Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find a way to expand the function $e^{e^x-1}$ into Maclaurin series but I don't know how to. I don't want to use the cumbersome Maclaurin formula of taking successive higher derivative.

Do you know how to nicely expand this function into Taylor series. I know that this is the generating function of Bell numbers.

Wolfram gives the expansion as:

$1-x+x^2+\dfrac{5x^3}{6}+\dfrac{5x^4}{8}...$

Comment: Any nice way to find the Taylor series would be a nice way to find the Bell numbers, and conversely. There are several that don't call for computing the derivatives. So the best you can do is look at the known ways to do that and hope to find one that suits your need. Wikipedia is pretty good on Bell numbers.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker: I wish to find a way to expand this functions. I have tried the derivative way and there is $e$ involved. I don't want that.

Answer (score 3):

The exponent is
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^x-1 = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now just plug this in the power series for the exponential function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{exp}(e^x-1) = 1&+& \left(x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots \right) \\
&+& \frac{1}{2} \left(x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots \right)^2 \\
&+& \frac{1}{6} \left(x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots \right)^3 \\
&+& \cdots  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Expand to whatever order you need ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{exp}(e^x-1) = \color{red}{1}+\color{red}{1}x+ \frac{\color{red}{2}x^2}{2}+ \frac{\color{red}{5}x^3}{3!} +\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
But of course ... as Ethan Bolker says in the comments the Bell numbers can be calculated much more easily using
\begin{eqnarray*}
B_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k} B_k.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +1 I was suggesting this in a comment when your answer appeared.

Comment: So you substitute the whole expression into $e^x-1$, how do you simplify them to get to the final answer?

Comment: It is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^X = 1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+ \frac{X^3}{6}+\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
with $X$ replaced with $x+x^2/2+ \cdots$.

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit: How do you simply them to get to the final answer $1+1x+\frac{2x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^3}{3!}...$

Comment: expand all the brackets and collect the $x^k$ terms.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Your technique is new to me so I have to say it is pretty marvelous, thank you!

Comment: Well, @JamesWarthington, it’s a natural thing to do when you have two series $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. As you might expect, it’s called the composition of $f$ and $g$, usually denoted $f\circ g$.

Comment: After trying out this method, I think differentiating is a better way to go. The computation will get messier as the power increases.

Comment: I try the derivative and it is also very messy haha...

Answer (score 1):

The composition of Taylor series for function such as $e^{f(x)}$ or $\log(f(x))$ requires patience first.

The trick I use is to first expand $f(x)$
$$f(x)=f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ and continue to get
$$e^{f(x)}=e^{f(x_0)}\left(1+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(f''(0)+f'(0)^2\right)+O\left(x^3\right)\right)$$
$$\log(f(x))=\log (f(0))+x\frac{ f'(0)}{f(0)}+\frac{1}{2} x^2
   \left(\frac{f''(0)}{f(0)}-\frac{f'(0)^2}{f(0)^2}\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the $n$th derivative of the function $e^{e^x}$ can be computed by
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-funct-derivative-eq}
\frac{\textrm{d}^ne^{e^x}}{\textrm{d} x^n}=e^{e^x}\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n,k)e^{kx},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
S(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}(-1)^{k-\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\ell^n
\end{equation*}
for $n\ge k\ge1$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind.

There are several proofs for this conclusion in the following paper:

1. Feng Qi, *Some inequalities for the Bell numbers*, Proceedings of the Indian Academy of Sciences--Mathematical Sciences **127** (2017), no. 4, 551--564; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s12044-017-0355-2.

This result has been generalized and applied in the following papers:

2. Feng Qi, *Some inequalities and an application of exponential polynomials*, Mathematical Inequalities & Applications **23** (2020), no. 1, 123--135; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/mia-2020-23-10.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some properties and an application of multivariate exponential polynomials*, Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences **43** (2020), no. 6, 2967--2983; available online at https://doi.org/10.1002/mma.6095.
4. Feng Qi, *Integral representations for multivariate logarithmic polynomials*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **336** (2018), 54--62; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2017.11.047.
5. Feng Qi, *On multivariate logarithmic polynomials and their properties*, Indagationes Mathematicae **29** (2018), no. 5, 1179--1192; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.indag.2018.04.002.